# Hive join between two tables

Tags: sql, hadoop, join, hive

This is the problema:
I've got this staging table:

```
key0    key1    timestamp   partition_key
5   5   2020-03-03 14:42:21.548 1
5   4   2020-03-03 14:40:11.871 1
4   3   2020-03-03 14:43:47.602 2
```

And this target table:

```
key0    key1    timestamp   partition_key
5   4   2020-03-03 13:43:16.695 1
5   5   2020-03-03 13:45:24.793 1
5   2   2020-03-03 13:47:30.668 1
5   1   2020-03-03 13:48:30.669 1
4   3   2020-03-03 13:53:47.602 2
43  3   2020-03-03 14:00:14.016 2
```

I want to get this output:

```
key0    key1    timestamp   partition_key
5   5   2020-03-03 14:42:21.548 1
5   4   2020-03-03 14:40:11.871 1
5   2   2020-03-03 13:47:30.668 1
5   1   2020-03-03 13:48:30.669 1
4   3   2020-03-03 14:43:47.602 2
43  3   2020-03-03 14:00:14.016 2
```

In the timestamp field, I want the most updated record when key0, key1, and partition_key. In addition, I want already existing records in the target table but that doesn't exist in the staging table

I tried first with this query:

```
select 
t1.key0,
t1.key1,
t1.timestamp,
t2.partition_key
from staging_table t2 
left outer join target_table t1 on 
t1.key0=t2.key0 AND
t1.key1=t2.key1 AND
t1.timestamp=t2.timestamp;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This looks like a prioritization query -- take everything from staging and then unmatched rows from the target.  I'm going to recommend `union all`:

```
select s.*
from staging s
union all
select t.*
from target t left join
     staging s
     on t.key0 = s.key0 and t.key1 = s.key1
where s.key0 is null;
```

This does assume that staging has the most recent rows -- which is true in your sample data.  If not, I would phrase this as:

```
select key0, key1, timestamp, partition_key
from (select st.*,
             row_number() over (partition by key0, key1 order by timestamp desc) as seqnum
      from ((select s.* from source s
            ) union all
            (select t.* from target t
            )
           ) st
     ) st
where seqnum = 1;
```

Answer (score 1):

You need `FULL JOIN` :

```
select COALESCE(t1.key0, T2.key0) AS key0, COALESCE(t1.key1, T2.KEY1) AS KEY1,
       COALESCE(t1.timestamp, T2.timestamp) AS timestamp, 
       COALESCE(t1.partition_key, t2.partition_key) AS partition_key
t2.partition_key
from staging_table t2 FULL JOIN 
     target_table t1
     on t1.key0 = t2.key0 AND t1.key1 = t2.key1 AND
        t1.timestamp = t2.timestamp;
```

Answer (score 1):

I think that you just want a `left join` and `coalesce()`:

```
select 
    t.key0,
    t.key1,
    coalesce(s.timestamp, t.timestamp) timestamp,
    t.partition_key
from target_table t 
left join  staging_table s 
    on  s.key0 = t2.key0 
    and s.key1 = t.key1 
    and s.partition_key = t.partition_key
```

For each record in `target_table`, this searches for a record in `staging_table` that has the same `(key0, key1, partition_key`). If such a record is available, we take use its `timestamp` in place of the `timestamp` from the `target_table`.